# Google signin popup on page refresh

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I implemented google signin in my webpage

however, when i refresh the page, there is some strange popup at the bottom of the page.

I don't know what's causing it or how to make it not appear.

how do i make it not appear?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample code on how you implemented the sign-in?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use your browser's [Inspect Element](http://dannguyen.github.io/NICAR/2012/02/25/nicar-2012-inspect-the-web-with-your-browsers-web-inspector/#getting_started) tool and find out the highest level of the element you want to get rid of, and apply `display:none;` to that selector in your CSS.

So for example, if that containing *DIV* you want to get rid of has ID of "ASDjkia". Then, in your CSS file, you would add:

```
div#ASDjkia { display: none; }
```

If it had the class "LKJAjwen", then in your CSS file, you would add:

```
div.LKJAjwen { display: none; }
```

---

**Edit:** (Thanks [Steven V for your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434735/google-signin-popup-on-page-refresh#comment36002845_23480434))

Why not hide the container div used for the sign-in link? Encapsulate it with your own ID, and hide that.

Comment: This is dangerous. Google minifies their class names and IDs (notice the completely unreadable class name and ID). They could change at any point in the future.

Comment: You're totally right, and that slipped my mind. Encapsulating that with another would be much better.

Comment: that wont work, because the name is ALWAYS different

Answer (score 0):

This is a notification when a user is signed in. It'll only display the first time a user comes back to your site if you're use page level config (config in meta tags) or rendering the button to trigger the sign in callback. It will display more often on localhost though, so that may be why you're seeing it a lot! If you're seeing it regularly on production, check that the cookiepolicy is set correctly for your site.